# Not Found: /build/three.module.js Django and Threejs uploading a OBJ file

Tags: javascript, html, django, three.js

```html
settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import posixpath
import os

import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ge6-ucd5%fz-feusu-v0c&c&6xk5=5nls!k9)7zz$l!19#(6i^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'three',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangothree.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangothree.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
PROJECT_ROOT = 'C:/DjangoThree'
```

i would be very grateful if someone help me, i've traying upload a obj file with Django and threejs but i get this error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhDQe.png)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhDQe.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti131.png also i'm uploading images JPG and PNG too and this upload correctly but the obj imge doesn't work in my localhost.

then, i don´t know if i'm importinting well the module or if my static files are wrong

```js
'use strict';

import * as THREE from  '../build/three.module.js'

import { TrackballControls } from "../jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js";
import { MTLLoader } from "../jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js";
import { OBJLoader2 } from "../jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js";
import { MtlObjBridge } from "../jsm/loaders/obj2/bridge/MtlObjBridge.js";
```

```css
this is a part of my TrackballControls.js

import {
    EventDispatcher,
    MOUSE,
    Quaternion,
    Vector2,
    Vector3
} from '../build/three.module.js';
```

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - OBJLoader2 basic usage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/site.css' %}" />
    <style>
        #glFullscreen {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            min-width: 640px;
            min-height: 360px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 0;
        }
        
        #example {
            width: 25%;
            height: 50%;
            margin-top: 250px;
            margin-left: 1010px;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        
        #feedback {
            color: darkorange;
        }
        
        #dat {
            user-select: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-Index: 200;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="glFullscreen">
        <canvas id="example"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="dat">

    </div>
    <div id="info">
        <a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - OBJLoader2 direct loader test
        <div id="feedback"></div>
    </div>
    <img src= "{% static 'img/preview1.jpg' %}">
    <img src= "{% static 'img/eimg.png' %}">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static 'js/alert.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="module" src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="module" src="{% static 'build/three.module.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="module" src="{% static './build/three.module.js' %}" ></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and this is how my project is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhDQe.png)

i hope that be suficient to explain me, thank u so much!

Comment: Do the rest of the JS files (like `TrackballControls.js`) work properly? Could you add your `settings.py`?

Comment: i think so, because the only problems are in the main and three.module.py
and i did it now i published the settings.py thanku!

Comment: or this is all project in github https://github.com/FabiSG/ThreejsDjango